# dirac's theorem not work

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am studing graph theory specifically hamiltonian cycles

I have a doubt with a exercise, it is a connected simple graph with 13 vertices, the book says that this graph has a hamilton cycle(truly it has)

each vertex has degree 2,3,4 or 5

By dirac's theorem this graph cannot have a hamilton cycle because $\delta$ (G) < $\frac{n}{2}$ where n = 13

does dirac's theorem work sometimes?

Comment: This isn't Dirac's theorem. Dirac's theorem states that _if_ the graph has every vertex of large degree, _then_ it has a Hamiltonian cycle. It tells you nothing about when graph has vertices of small degrees.

Comment: @Jose Vega: A picture of the graph in your exercise could help the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Dirac's theorem says that

**IF** you have $\delta(G)\geq \frac{n}{2}$ **THEN** the graph is hamiltonian.

$P\implies Q$ is **not** the same thing as $\neg P\implies \neg Q$.

Just because $\delta(G)<\frac{n}{2}$ it is not implied that the graph is not hamiltonian.

Take for trivial counterexample the graph $C_{100}$, the cycle of length 100.  This graph is clearly hamiltonian since the graph *itself* is a hamiltonian cycle, yet the degree of every vertex is $2$ which is much less than $\frac{100}{2}=50$.

The information you have given us so far is not enough to confirm whether the graph does or does not have a hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: thank you
I will research more

Comment: This website helped me to understand your response
http://www.ctl.ua.edu/math103/hamilton/analyzin.htm